Migrating from cron-editor to ngx-cron-editor
Migrated my application to angular 18, when i checked the cron editor page it's not showing the cron editor. Am using cron-editor and it's last release was 5 years ago. So i planned to move to ngx-cron-editor. Am new to UI so i tried what is present in the official page but am getting some issues
cronExpression = new FormControl('0 0 0 1/1 * ? *');
  public cronOptions: CronOptions = {
    defaultTime: "00:00:00",

    hideMinutesTab: true,
    hideHourlyTab: true,
    hideDailyTab: false,
    hideWeeklyTab: false,
    hideMonthlyTab: false,
    hideYearlyTab: false,
    hideAdvancedTab: true,
    hideSpecificWeekDayTab: true,
    hideSpecificMonthWeekTab : true,

    use24HourTime: true,
    hideSeconds: false,

    cronFlavor: "quartz"
 };

<cron-editor [formControl]="cronExpression" [options]="cronOptions"></cron-editor>

not sure how to handle the below error
src\assets\js\pdf.worker.loader.js:18 2024-11-08T12:48:00.447Z RuntimeError: NG01203: No value accessor for form control unspecified name attribute. Find more at https://angular.dev/errors/NG01203
    at _throwMissingValueAccessorError (forms.mjs:3256:11)
    at setUpControl (forms.mjs:3029:13)
    at FormControlDirective.ngOnChanges (forms.mjs:4659:13)
    at FormControlDirective.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.mjs:4113:14)
    at callHookInternal (core.mjs:5153:14)
    at callHook (core.mjs:5184:9)
    at callHooks (core.mjs:5134:17)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:5084:9)
    at refreshView (core.mjs:13798:21)
    at detectChangesInView (core.mjs:13999:9)

Can someone please point me how to implement ngx-cron-editor
